# How do I install Code::Blocks for Linux on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, code-blocks

I want to install http://www.codeblocks.org/ on Ubuntu Linux.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a good walkthrough](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks_nightly_build_on_Ubuntu) on the Code::Blocks wiki for installing on Ubuntu.

> This is a quick guide to get
>   Code::Blocks up and running on your
>   Ubuntu based Linux distribution. It is
>   also going to make sure you can
>   develop wxWidgets applications on your
>   box as well. Look at the bottom of
>   this guide for a complete command line
>   that will install all the packages in
>   one operation.

Answer (score 2):

[Installing Code::Blocks nightly build on Ubuntu](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks_nightly_build_on_Ubuntu)
from the more generic Wiki page, [Installing Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite program on ubuntu can also help with installing many other programs as well as Code::Block

[Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To install code blocks12.11  on ubuntu 12.04 you need all this  packages :

- libjpeg62_6b1-2ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
- libtiff4_3.9.2-2ubuntu0.13_i386.deb
- libwxbase2.8-0_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2_i386.deb
- libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2_i386.deb
- wx2.8-headers_2.8.12.1-12_i386.deb
- build-essential_11.6.tar.gz
- codeblocks_12.11-1_i386-debian-testing.tar.bz2

In the console window these commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i libjpeg62_6b1-2ubuntu1.1_i386.deb libtiff4_3.9.2-2ubuntu0.13_i386.deb libwxbase2.8-0_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2_i386.deb libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2_i386.deb wx2.8-headers_2.8.12.1-12_i386.deb
tar -xvf build-essential_11.6.tar.gz
tar -xvf codeblocks_12.11-1_i386-debian-testing.tar.bz2
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```